# Short story about a man whose thinks his life on earth is a punishment from his home planet

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In a short story, a man suffers traumas and setbacks -- a car accident, death of family members -- and becomes  obsessed with the idea that he was sent from another planet to live out a life on Earth as punishment for his sins.

Then he dies, and wakes up to find that he was indeed sent to live out a life on Earth, but that other planet is a place of misery, and his life on Earth  -- imperfect, but still good enough in its own right, and much better than life on the hell-planet -- was an exceptional award for his virtue.

I read the story maybe 20 or 30 years ago. I do not remember what magazine or book.

What was that story?

Comment: Dammit! I knew there was something odd going on with my life

Comment: Sounds like something Robert Sheckley might have written.

Comment: Sounds like a Harlan Ellison story, title escapes me though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is Strange Wine by Ellison (someone just identified it for me) [Man committing suicide wakes to find that Earth is an alien simulation of a perfect world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260205/man-committing-suicide-wakes-to-find-that-earth-is-an-alien-simulation-of-a-perf/260211#260211)

Comment: You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to explain why you think this is the correct story, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question.