# Man committing suicide wakes to find that Earth is an alien simulation of a perfect world

Tags: story-identification

A man who is miserable kills himself only to find that his life on Earth was a reward - since Earth is much better than the life on the alien world on which he's from.

Comment: Welcome Andrew. Please take our [tour] and have a read of  our [help] for guidance. See our [story ID checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and try edit in some more details e.g is it a book, short story, comic strip, film, TV series, what language was it in, what year did it appear etc..

Comment: Was the man really, really small, blue, and speaking with a pseudo-Scottish accent?

Comment: I think I recall a story, not that Earth was a simulation but a place where his species was sent as a reward. I recall something like Earth was called the "pleasure planet" even though the alien had had a difficult life as a human. He wakes after his suicide on a desert planet or something.

Comment: @DavidW - my first thought as well, "Crivens! he's a  Nac Mac Feegle"

Comment: I'm almost positive that this question (or very very similar) was asked before, but I can't find it.  I don't think suicide was mentioned thought.  Anyone else know where this is?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a match for the Harlan Ellison story "[Strange Wine](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56426)" (*Amazing Science Fiction*, June 1976.)    Although it doesn't say that Earth is a simulation, the story is otherwise as you've described it: the protagonist, Plydo aka Willis Kaw, was sent away from his alien world to Earth, where he falsely believed that his exile to Earth was a punishment, and returns to it after his death on the Earth, where he commits suicide.  The story ends:

> He remembered the rain, and the sleep, and the feel of beach sand beneath his feet, and ocean rolling in to whisper its eternal song, and on just such nights as those he had despised on Earth, he slept and dreamed good dreams.
>
> Of life as Willis Kaw, life on the pleasure planet.

Comment: Thank you.  That's certainly the right answer.