# Story about alien living as human on Earth as a reward but he returns to his own world and find out truth

Tags: story-identification

This might be a very old, 1930s but probably later; probably no later than 1970s.
Someone lives a very difficult life on Earth and perhaps wonders what he did to deserve such an existence. However, the situation is temporary and he wakes up to find himself in a very non-human body on a terrible desert planet. He discovers that he was rewarded for some service rendered to his species by being sent to "Earth, the pleasure planet" -- but as mentioned, this is not forever and he resumes some very challenging existence. I don't recall if the sole reason is environmental -- there may also have been a long-lasting war in which he was perhaps a high-ranking officer given this privilege due to some military success. I don't recall what was so bad about his life on Earth -- it may have been financial or family problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds a lot like *[Strange Wine](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56426)*, a short story by Harlan Ellison. First published in Amazing Science Fiction in June 1976, it's more recent than the 1930s, but fits with your recollection of not being later than the 1970s.

It concerns a man named Willis Kaw, who leads a life on Earth which he regards as being a torment. He seems to remember leading a happier life elsewhere:

> He dreamed of his home world and — perhaps because the sun was high
> and the ocean made eternal sounds — he was able to bring much of it
> back. The bright green sky, the skimmers swooping and rising overhead,
> the motes of pale yellow light that flamed and then floated up and
> were lost to sight. He felt himself in his real body, the movement of
> many legs working in unison, carrying him across the mist sands, the
> smell of alien flowers in his mind...

He wonders why he has been sent away to lead this miserable existence on Earth:

> [He] knew he had been sent away for doing something bad. He knew he
> had been condemned to this planet, this Earth, for having perhaps
> committed a crime. But he could not remember what it was.

Finally in desperation he commits suicide, and finds himself back on his homeworld. There he finds that his stint on Earth was not a punishment, but a very special reward, of "life on the pleasure planet."

The story is available for loan from the [Internet Library](https://archive.org/details/strangewinefifte00elli), from the Ellison short story collection *Strange Wine*.

Comment: If accepted, this would be a duplicate of  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/252688/short-story-about-a-man-whose-thinks-his-life-on-earth-is-a-punishment-from-his/260236#260236 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260205/man-committing-suicide-wakes-to-find-that-earth-is-an-alien-simulation-of-a-perf/260211#260211

Comment: Yes, the last line makes it the same story.